# Getting implicit resolution and type projection to work? Probably need a workaround

Tags: scala

I've confirmed this is an issue in 2.10.4 and 2.11.1

My goal is to combine implicits and type projection... I'm wondering if there is a way to get this to work?

```
trait Plat[P <: Plat[P]] {
  type Keyed[_, _]
}

class MPlat extends Plat[MPlat] {
  type Keyed[K, V] = (K, TraversableOnce[V])
}

trait Prod[P <: Plat[P], T, This <: Prod[P, T, This]] {
  def name(str: String)(implicit wrap: Wrapper[P, T, This]): This = wrap(this)
}

trait KProd[P <: Plat[P], K, V] extends Prod[P, P#Keyed[K, V], KProd[P, K, V]]

object Wrapper {
  implicit def keyedWrapper[P <: Plat[P], K, V]: Wrapper[P, P#Keyed[K, V], KProd[P, K, V]]  =
    new Wrapper[P, P#Keyed[K, V], KProd[P, K, V]] {
      override def apply(p: Prod[P, P#Keyed[K, V], KProd[P, K, V]]): KProd[P, K, V] = throw new Exception("we made it!")
    }
}
sealed trait Wrapper[P <: Plat[P], T, This <: Prod[P, T, This]] {
  def apply(p: Prod[P, T, This]): This
}
```

The following should work

```
(new Prod[MPlat, (Int, TraversableOnce[Int]), KProd[MPlat, Int, Int]] { }).name("hey")
```

and indeed, this works:

```
keyedWrapper[MPlat, Int, Int](new Prod[MPlat, (Int, TraversableOnce[Int]), KProd[MPlat, Int, Int]] { })
```

I think this is a bug in the scala type checker, but I'm wondering if there is a workaround (while keeping the same semantics) that will make this resolution work successfully?